# Sort Delimited file column wise

Tags: unix, sorting, sed, awk

My Input file is like below i need to sort this file based on delimiter '~' ie.,column 1 by ascending and column 5 by descending.

```
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~1~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~2~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~W~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~X~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~Z~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~i~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~j~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~m~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~n~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~o~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~p~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~q~  
200407~20043~JUL-04~200307~P~  
200407~20043~JUL-04~200307~V~  
200407~20043~JUL-04~200307~k~  
200408~20043~AUG-04~200308~P~  
200408~20043~AUG-04~200308~V~  
200408~20043~AUG-04~200308~k~  
200409~20043~SEP-04~200309~P~  
200409~20043~SEP-04~200309~V~  
200409~20043~SEP-04~200309~k~  
200410~20044~OCT-04~200310~P~  
200410~20044~OCT-04~200310~V~  
200410~20044~OCT-04~200310~k~  
200411~20044~NOV-04~200311~P~  
200411~20044~NOV-04~200311~V~  
200411~20044~NOV-04~200311~k~  
200412~20044~DEC-04~200312~P~  
200412~20044~DEC-04~200312~V~  
200412~20044~DEC-04~200312~k~
```

I tried below command, but could not get desired result

```
sort -t$'~' -k1 -k5r filename
```

My resulting file should match like below

```
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~q~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~p~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~o~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~n~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~m~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~j~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~i~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~Z~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~X~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~W~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~2~  
010001~01001~JAN-00~009901~1~  
200407~20043~JUL-04~200307~k~  
200407~20043~JUL-04~200307~V~  
200407~20043~JUL-04~200307~P~  
200408~20043~AUG-04~200308~k~  
200408~20043~AUG-04~200308~V~  
200408~20043~AUG-04~200308~P~  
200409~20043~SEP-04~200309~k~  
200409~20043~SEP-04~200309~V~  
200409~20043~SEP-04~200309~P~  
200410~20044~OCT-04~200310~k~  
200410~20044~OCT-04~200310~V~  
200410~20044~OCT-04~200310~P~  
200411~20044~NOV-04~200311~k~  
200411~20044~NOV-04~200311~V~  
200411~20044~NOV-04~200311~P~  
200412~20044~DEC-04~200312~k~  
200412~20044~DEC-04~200312~V~  
200412~20044~DEC-04~200312~P~
```

Can some one help me to resolve this.

Comment: why `q,p..` is before `Z` in last column?

Comment: @Kent: case-sensitive ASCII (reverse) order; lower-case letters have larger numbers than upper-case, so that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

Tell the [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html)
where to stop matching as well as where to start.

```
sort -t$'~' -k1,1 -k5,5r filename
```

Without the `,1` (and `,5`), the first comparison runs from column 1 to the end of the line.

POSIX says:

> The notation:
>
> ```
> -k field_start[type][,field_end[type]]
> ```
>
> shall define a key field that begins at `field_start` and ends at `field_end` inclusive, unless `field_start` falls beyond the end of the line or after `field_end`, in which case the key field is empty. A missing `field_end` shall mean the last character of the line.

Comment: +1 but do we really `$'~'` I think `sort -t '~' -k1,1 -k5,5r file` should also work.

Comment: You don't need the `$'~'` and `'~'` would work fine.  I didn't bother to correct or note that.